# Sql - Open Json insert to Table

Tags: sql, json

I have a part of my Stored Procedured which retrieving the data received from my Json, then i used a OPENJSON in order to be display in a table format.

but how can i insert it into existing table with the same declare column names in my OpenJson?.

```
 Declare @JsonString varchar(MAX) = (Select DataReceived from ItemTransaction where 
                        DocType ='LoadItem' and BranchCode = @pBranchCode and TranNo =  @pTranNo)


Sample ReplyData string
'{"status":{"code":"0","name":"RCRD_LOADED","status":"Success","message":"Record sucessfully loaded"},"records":[{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"2310","itemid":"00999","displayname":"Neck - Tie","locationquantityonhand":"9996","locationquantityavailable":"9994","locationquantitycommitted":"9994","locationquantitybackordered":"9994"}]}'


SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON ( @JsonString,'$."records"')  
WITH (   
              RecordType   varchar(200) '$.recordtype' ,  
              ItemID     varchar     '$.id',  
              ItemDetails varchar(200) '$.itemid',  
              Quantity int          '$.locationquantityonhand'  
 ) 
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have table with the similar schema as OPENSJSON and insert into it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestJson
(
RecordType   varchar(200) 
,ItemID     varchar     
,ItemDetails varchar(200)   
,Quantity int               
)

DECLARE @JsonString VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'{"status":{"code":"0","name":"RCRD_LOADED","status":"Success","message":"Record sucessfully loaded"},"records":[{"recordtype":"inventoryitem","id":"2310","itemid":"00999","displayname":"Neck - Tie","locationquantityonhand":"9996","locationquantityavailable":"9994","locationquantitycommitted":"9994","locationquantitybackordered":"9994"}]}'


INSERT INTO TestJson
SELECT * FROM  
OPENJSON ( @JsonString,'$."records"')  
WITH (   
              RecordType   varchar(200) '$.recordtype' ,  
              ItemID     varchar        '$.id',  
              ItemDetails varchar(200)  '$.itemid',  
              Quantity int              '$.locationquantityonhand'  
 ) 

 SELECT * FROM TestJson
```

```
+---------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|  RecordType   | ItemID | ItemDetails | Quantity |
+---------------+--------+-------------+----------+
| inventoryitem |      2 |       00999 |     9996 |
+---------------+--------+-------------+----------+
```